# Put the object with one side on the plane

Tags: three.js, geometry

I have the object like this:
[image: ][1]]

and I need to find the biggest flat side of the object (in this case it is a back side of the face) automatically and put it with this side on the some simple plane geometry.

Is it possible?

Comment: Compute the convex hull and select the set of adjacent faces with maximal surface area to curvature ratio

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, ok. As i understood I need to use QuickHull. But after this, how to translate whole model and put them on the plane with this computing faces?

Comment: Once you find the set of faces described by @meowgoesthedog, you can calculate their collective center and normal ,which you can use as a reference for the transformation of the whole object. You will be translating that center onto the plane, and rotating the object so the normal matches (though it probably needs to be inverted to) the plane's normal.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, @meowgoesthedog and TheJim01, thank you guys for ideas. Maybe my code will be useful for anyone..

```
const faceCentering = (model) => {

  const quickhull = new QuickHull()
  quickhull.setFromObject(model)

  const ePoints = quickhull.computeExtremes()
  const centerX = 0.5 * ( ePoints.max[0].point.x + ePoints.min[0].point.x );
  const centerY = 0.5 * ( ePoints.max[1].point.y + ePoints.min[1].point.y );
  const centerZ = 0.5 * ( ePoints.max[2].point.z + ePoints.min[2].point.z );

  const maxAriaFace = quickhull.faces
                      .map(face => face.area )
                      .reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b) )

  const pivotFace = quickhull.faces
                    .filter(obj => obj.area === maxAriaFace)[0]


  //rotating with the "back side model" face's normal along yAxis
  const newDir = new Vector3(pivotFace.normal.x, pivotFace.normal.y, -pivotFace.normal.z);
  const pos = new Vector3().addVectors(newDir, model.position);
  model.lookAt(pos);

  // centroid position
  model.children[0].geometry.applyMatrix( new Matrix4()
  .makeTranslation(-centerX, -centerY, -pivotFace.midpoint.z))

}
```